# Are there any toxic or dangerous food pairings?

Tags: medical-science, nutrition, safety

**Are there any foods that are harmless when eaten alone yet are dangerous or toxic when eaten together with another otherwise innocuous food?**

There can obviously be problems if you combine acidic foods with basic foods.  I'm looking more for pairings that cause some sort of chemical reaction that produces a toxin and/or some pharmacological [product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_%28chemistry%29).

This question is motivated by [some claims that have been made](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/14249/is-this-a-true-you-should-use-garlic-with-pork-and-ginger-with-beef-and-never-vi/17822#17822) over on [Cooking.SX](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/).  For example, it is claimed that the combination of crab and persimmon is toxic.

I could have sworn that I had seen a similar question asked either here or on Cooking.SX, however, I couldn't seem to find it after doing a search.

Comment: A common story in Belgium and the Netherlands is that you should not mix [tonic and baileys](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sr2c0EKVlk4), because it would form a stone in your stomach, which is [not](http://www.delta.tudelft.nl/nl/archief/artikel/apekool/9035) the case (link is in dutch).

Comment: like a 2-part poison

Comment: @ESultanik - I suggest you make your question about a specific claim, we can't provide answers where the answers are just a list of "possible claims"

Comment: **Note**: please don't make this a list question.

Comment: @Sklivvz: Now that there are two answers, how should I deal with this?  Should I edit the question to only ask about the crab/persimmon combination?  I intended this question to have a simple "yes/no" answer (*i.e.*, any single counter-example is sufficient).

Comment: I don't think this is different from any other SE question. Accept the best answer. Maybe someone will come up with a site providing an extensive list, or a great study, or whatnot. :-)

Comment: `There can obviously be problems if you combine acidic foods with basic foods`. Sorry, but why would that be?

Comment: @nico: Well, not necessarily toxicity problems, but reactivity.

Comment: I got sick as a dog on Orange juice and Vodka once, puked up toenails, does that qualify. Those were the days.

Comment: I heard the 'stone in the stomach' thing is gooey fondue followed by cold lager - this allegedly causes the bolus of fondue to set into an impervious lump . . . well, sounds more likely than tonic and Baileys.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Yes**

One example that springs to mind is the combination of certain species of [mushrooms and alcoholic beverages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disulfiram#Similarly_acting_substances). The mushrooms contain metabolites which inhibit one of the enzymes involved in breaking down ethanol, leading to a buildup of the aldehyde ethanal, which is unpleasant.

> The ink cap--Coprinus atramentarius (Bulliard ex Fries) Fries--is responsible for poisoning when ingested with alcohol

—[source](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/1344910)

Comment: +1, although it could certainly be argued that alcohol doesn't qualify as *harmless when eaten alone*

Answer (score 1):

One common claim I was told as a child is that it is [unhealthy to eat fish and leafy vegetables (like spinach)](http://www.masenka.be/2008/02/15/be-careful-with-combining-fish-and-spinach/), due to the formation of nitrosamines. This seems to be more of a [theoretical risk than an actual cause](http://www.food-info.net/uk/qa/qa-fp6.htm) of illness, although I did find one paper [linking fish and high-nitrate vegetables to liver cancer](http://www.environmentalhealthnews.org/ehs/newscience/eating-vegetables-with-fish-increases-cancer-risk).