# Is combining different types of foods unhealthy?

Tags: nutrition

According to [this article](http://beyondhealth.com/media/wysiwyg/kadro/articles/FoodCombining.pdf):

It is good to combine vegetables with either proteins or
starches, but:

- Do not combine proteins and starches (meat and potatoes, fish and rice, etc.).
- Generally, eat fruit alone. Acid fruits may be consumed
  with sweet fruits, in which case, the acid fruits should be
  eaten first. Acid fruits can also be combined with nuts
  and seeds.
- Do not combine melons with anything (even other fruits,
  except other melons).

Are there any studies that back these claims?

This is different from [Are there any toxic or dangerous food pairings?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/6283/), in which he specifically mentions that he is *not* asking about general food categories as being unhealthy, but rather specific foods that can produce toxins when combined.

Comment: I have edited to explain why it's not a duplicate.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a notable claim. It's from a single website which exists primarily to sell magic potions at vastly inflated prices. Some of their products are literally titled, 'magic'.

Comment: A google search for "food combining" comes up with many websites with similar claims.

Comment: You should probably narrow it down to a single claim, like meats and starches, or melons. After all, the question in the title is specifically already answered in the linked question.  If the question is accepted, you could always open new question for the other two points.

Comment: @AdamPhelps Which of the points is answered in the other question? My question is about food groups, not about specific foods (I guess besides the melons, which are a specific food). None of the three points are discussed at all in the other question, although the one that asks the question makes an assumption that mixing acidic and basic foods is a problem (I didn't know that there even is such a thing as a basic food).

Comment: I think you misread me. The title is answered. Namely "Is combining different types of food unhealthy?"  I suggested narrowing the claim to, for example, "Is combining starches and meats unhealthy?" Though, you might need to find more examples of the claim.  You seem to be making a distinction between types and specific foods, but I don't see that this distinction really makes sense. What constitutes a "type"? family? genera? species? sub-species?  Does it really matter?

Comment: @AdamPhelps I guess you are correct; that distinction is irrelevant. You are correct about the title being answered, but I don't know how to change it. I wouldn't want to separate these claims, because I see these same claims all in conjunction with each other on different websites.

Comment: If all these sites list similar claims, do they have a common name or proposed mechanism of action?  If so, perhaps you can use that to dial down the scope of the question.  Maybe a good start would be to link up some more examples of the claim?

Comment: We've also other questions about specific food combinations.

Comment: @Sklivvz Such as what?

Comment: @AdamPhelps It seems that this is called the Hay diet.

Comment: A quick search here only mentions the Hay diet in passing in an answer to a question regarding pH and mood.  So maybe that would be alright. Maybe something like "Is there any scientific evidence supporting the Hay Diet?"  But I'm not exactly a veteran here, so it won't be up to me.  It should clear up the duplicate problem. I would address the not significant bit too though, by citing a few other examples.

Comment: In the end, now that I figured out what it's called, I found that the Wikipedia article already answers my questions about studies done.